# What is the best approach to insert a record between two sequencial rows?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a simple sequential table such:

```
  ID   | Name | Rank
=======+======+=====
  327  | Ali  | 1
-------+------+-----
  846  | Sara | 2
-------+------+-----
  657  | Dani | 3
-------+------+-----
         ...
```

the `ID` is primary key and indexed, also the `Rank` is indexed too. I have couples of these records, and what i want is that insert a record between records of this table in `SQL Server`, as keeps its sequences without breaking the ranking.

for example i insert `Sahar` by into the above table with ranking 2, It cause to shifting greater ranks , so :

```
  ID   | Name | Rank
=======+======+=====
  327  | Ali  | 1
-------+------+-----
  196  | Sahar| 2     ----> Inserted
-------+------+-----
  846  | Sara | 3
-------+------+-----
  657  | Dani | 4
-------+------+-----
         ...
```

I have searched and i have found some solution to do it for instance :

```
UPDATE TABLE table SET Rank += 1 WHERE Rank >= 2;
INSERT INTO TABLE (Rank, ...) VALUES (2, ...);
```

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962867/insert-into-a-row-at-specific-position-into-sql-server-table-with-pk), or another approach may be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354070/how-to-insert-row-between-two-rows-and-give-it-priority-in-database). and some other answers i found but all of them have a heavy cost in operation.

Also may I need to change some `Ranks` or exchange two `Ranks` so.

In the other hand i have to do it in `UPDATE`, `Delete` and `Insert` `Triggers` or else-ever you recommend.

1. Is there a mechanism such as `identity(1,1)` or other built-in
   service in `SQL Server` which aims to solve this issue?
2. If NO, what is the best approach in performance aspect of this
       operation?( the answer should have a good explanation about
       implementation place (Trigger or ...), Indexing issue and also may
       be need to change my table definition)

Thanks.

Comment: Is your rank based on something else that would allow you to re-calculate it? If not, you'll probably just have to do an update. Don't see how triggers could help you in this.

Comment: @JamesZ, No. the concept of rank is completely sole and it depends on just to the person which there is not any other data to produce the rank from that.
The update should be in a trigger, because i want to be able to guarantee the sequence or the Rank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your table has `N` rows with `Rank` from `1` to `N`, and you insert a new row with `Rank=2`, then you'll have to `UPDATE` (i.e. change) values in `N-2` rows. You'll have to write a lot of changes to the table. I'm afraid there is no magic way to speed it up.

If you really have to update the `Rank`, that is.

But, maybe, you don't **really** need to have the `Rank` as an integer without gaps.

The real purpose of the `Rank` is to define a certain order of rows. To define an order you need to know which row comes after each row. So, when a user says that he wants to add `Sahar` with ranking `2` it really means that `Sahar` should go after `Ali`, but before `Sara`, so the rank of the new rows can be set to, say, `(1+2)/2 = 1.5`.

So, if you make `Rank` a float you would be able to insert new rows in the middle of the table without changing values of the `Rank` of all other rows.

If you want to present `Rank` to the user as a sequence of integer numbers without gaps use something like:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FloatRank) AS IntegerRankWithoutGaps
```

Besides, if you delete a row, you don't need to update all rows of a table as well. The persisted `FloatRank` value would have a gap, but it will disappear when `ROW_NUMBER` is applied.

Technically, you can't keep dividing an 8-byte float interval in half indefinitely, so once in a while you should run a maintenance procedure that "normalizes" your float ranks and updates all rows in a table. But, at least this costly procedure could be run not often and when the load on the system is minimal.

Also, you can start with float values not `1`, but further apart. For example, instead of `1, 2, 3, 4...` start with `1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, ...`.

Comment: I voted your answer because of reducing `Delete` (and any manipulation) operation cost. In conclusion, the main advantage of your approach is the lower cost in data manipulation. BUT it causes increase data reading cost, because of rank normalization (First problem). and if we don't normalize then may have gap in rank numbers and it will be bad in our UI phase(second problem) anyway I'm gonna accept your answer but may be need a few moments waiting to achieve a better answer ! Thank you.

Comment: In general case it can be very costly to maintain rank numbers **without gaps** as the data is inserted and deleted, because you have to make sure that no two different transactions update the table at the same time. Using `ROW_NUMBER` is a trade-off, but it should be relatively cheap, especially when you have an index on the underlying column. If there is an index, `ROW_NUMBER` would not have to do a sort.

Comment: Actually, it all depends on the frequency of inserts/deletes/updates and reads. If there are few inserts, but many reads it may be better to recalculate and update ranks as the data is inserted. You can't make recalculation cheaper, but it is possible to delay paying this cost.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and transparent way is to add column where you will define the sequence of rows in your table and than create clustered index on that column. This index will keep the data as you want.

Comment: every recommendation are welcome!:) , It seems to be a good idea but I need to see more details about your solution.

Comment: what kind of details you need?

Comment: I mean that where do you save the`Rank` which i have explained it in my question? how you deal with the gaps ? how you claim your approach has better performance on inserting data and reading them, by grantee preserving the ranking sequence order without any gaps ?

Comment: Let's separate between 2 terms: sequence in the table and row rank. I believe that you have to store row sequence/position instead of rank and calculate the rank on the fly. In case you calculate the rank during insert/delete - you process will stop some day due performance reason. RDBMS isn't good for such operations.

Comment: "`RDBMS` isn't good for such operations". so what is your suggestion instead of?

Comment: To be honest there is the need to understand why the sequence of rows is so important. The main advantage of RDMS is usage of logical instead of physical rows location, there is what R is for. Anyway the common way to keep rows in some particular physical order is clustered index on MSSQL or IOT on Oracle. In any case you have to define between which records the new record has to come and that shouldn't affect overall performance.